# How to evaluate the limit of this defined integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

Having a hard time finding this limit, it must be some natural log replacement I figured but I quite don't know how to replace it as such

$\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(n\int _0^1\:\left(\frac{x^n}{\left(x^n+x+1\right)}dx\right)\right)$

Managed to see that it can be written as almost the natural log by doing this thing here:

$\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\int _0^1\left(\frac{\left(nx^{n-1}+1-1\right)}{\left(x^n+x+1\right)}dx\right)\:\:\right)$

$\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\left(ln\left(3\right)-\int _0^1\left(\frac{1}{\left(x^n+x+1\right)}dx\right)\right)\:\:\right)$

Still have to solve this one:
$\int _0^1\left(\frac{1}{\left(x^n+x+1\right)}dx\right)$

Comment: I think so there is mistake in 3rd line.

Comment: @RAHUL it was, ln(3)

Comment: Yaa, so that integrand is only left to solve

Comment: You can remove the $n$ at the front and bring it in. Note that as $n\to\infty$, $nx^{n}=nx^{n-1}$

Comment: $$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{x^{n}+x+1}$$ converges to $0.69..$ as $n$ approach $\infty$

Comment: @RAHUL thanks for the idea of putting the n in the limit, helped me figure it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I found it eventually! I had to do a substitution...[image]

Comment: Use mathjax tools for formatting. By the way, glad you got it.